# Is A Class Member Variable Bound Or Free (In Terms Of Combinators)?

Tags: c#, functional-programming, combinators

While I realize I'm not being very rigorous, I'm pretty sure the definition of a combinator in simple terms is simply a function with no free variables. For example,

```
f(x,y) = x + y
```

would be a combinator and

```
f(x,y) = x * 2
```

would not be because y would be free.

So given that understanding would a member variable in a class definition be considered "free"?  I'm guessing it would but I wanted to check my assumption.  Code like this C# example:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class BoundOrFree
    {
        private int _i = 0;

        public int f(int x, int y)
        {
            return x + y + _i;
        }
    }
}
```

In the BoundOrFree.f member function is _i free?  Would f therefore not be a combinator?  I'm assuming the answer to both of those questions would be yes but I wanted to confirm my assumption.

Comment: `_i` in this case - global var and not a parameter to `f` function so i think this equals `f(x,y) = x + y + 2` and seems all params bounded

Comment: I don't think lambda calculus theory can be applied on object-oriented, mutable code.

Comment: @Grundy x + y + 2?  Am I missing something?  I'd expect it to be x + y + 0

Comment: not matter value :-) this anyway not a parameter for function :-) here i mean that you can replace `_i` with a number and semantic not changed, also `2` get from your sample `f(x,y) = x * 2` :-D

Comment: Ah. Ok.  I understand you now.

Comment: "would not be because y would be free." --- you misinterpret the "free" term in this case. Free variable is the one that was captured from the outer scope (via a closure). So `f(x,y) = x * 2` **is** a combinator.

Comment: Answering your question - the `BoundOrFree::f` function is not a combinator, since it uses variables other than its only arguments.

Comment: You should post that as an answer @zerkms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> would not be because y would be free

you misinterpret the "free" term in this case. Free variable is the one that was captured from the outer scope (via a closure). So `f(x,y) = x * 2` **is** a combinator.

Answering your question

> In the BoundOrFree.f member function is _i free? Would f therefore not be a combinator?

the `BoundOrFree::f` function is not a combinator, since it uses variables other than its only arguments.